# what is the minimal balance for staking xlm

Tags: xlm

when i try to participate in the staking i have this message in my wallet
Your balance is too low to participate in staking on the Stellar network

What is the min balance?

Answer (score 3):

it seems its a scam. I sent 39 coins to test said too low sent 600 more said too low..
must be scam

Comment: I just tried to send my coins back to Kraken and guess what, it wont let you. DO NOT DO IT